# Login/Signup using LinkedIn api

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, flask-login

I want integrate login/signup using Linkedin in Flask but getting errors. I have setup same redirect_URI in LInkedIn developer app and in flask app, but still it is not redirecting me to the authorization page.

I tried the following way;

```
# For LinkedIn OAuth
linkedin = oauth.remote_app(
    'linkedin',
    consumer_key='*********',
    consumer_secret='*********',
    request_token_params={
        'scope': 'r_basicprofile',
        'state': 'RandomString',
    },
    base_url='https://api.linkedin.com/v1/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://www.linkedin.com/oauth2/accessToken',
    authorize_url='https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization',
)

@app.route("/linkedinlogin")
def linkedinlogin():
    return linkedin.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True))


@app.route('/linkedinlogin/authorized')
def authorized():
    resp = linkedin.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['linkedin_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = linkedin.get('people/~')
    return jsonify(me.data)


@linkedin.tokengetter
def get_linkedin_oauth_token():
    return session.get('linkedin_token')


def change_linkedin_query(uri, headers, body):
    auth = headers.pop('Authorization')
    headers['x-li-format'] = 'json'
    if auth:
        auth = auth.replace('Bearer', '').strip()
        if '?' in uri:
            uri += '&oauth2_access_token=' + auth
        else:
            uri += '?oauth2_access_token=' + auth
    return uri, headers, body

linkedin.pre_request = change_linkedin_query
```

This gives me an error that redirect_uri does not match, but the redirect uri is exactly same; i,e `<http://localhost:5000/linkedinlogin/authorized>`

I am testing it on localhost

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)